# Como colocar um incremento dentro de um laço FOR?

Tags: java

Observem o código por favor;

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getArquivo())));
        File arquivoLeitura = new File(getArquivo());
        LineNumberReader linhaLeitura = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(arquivoLeitura));
        linhaLeitura.skip(arquivoLeitura.length());
        int qtdLinha  = linhaLeitura.getLineNumber() + 1;

        String linha = null;

        for (int i = 1; i  <= qtdLinha;  i++) {

                linha = reader.readLine();
                String[] dadosUsuario = linha.split(VIRGULA);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dadosUsuario));
                System.out.println( dadosUsuario[0]);
                System.out.println( dadosUsuario[1]);

                System.out.println( dadosUsuario[2]);
                System.out.println( dadosUsuario[3]);
                System.out.println( dadosUsuario[4]);
                System.out.println(dadosUsuario[5]);
                System.out.println("--------------------------");

                if (pessoaJuridicaPublicaService.getPorId(Long.parseLong(dadosUsuario[1])) == null) {
                int j = j + 1;
                }



        }
            reader.close();
```

Ele esta gerando esse erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se trata de um upload de arquivos csv, quando eu faço o upload de arquivos, ele percorre todas as linhas que existem no arquivo csv;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa linha de código irá verifica se uns dos campos esteja vazio, então eu gostaria de contar quantos campos vazio eu posso encontrar na variável  dadosUsusario[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNHQy.png).

O problema é que o Laço FOR não está permitindo eu colocar um contador dentro da condição IF.
Como faço para corrigir esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema na sua solução é que a variável `j` foi criada dentro do `if` o que faz com que só exista no `if` e não possa ser usada noutros locais. Para além disso ao fazer `int j = j + 1;` faz com que a variável receba o valor com base em `j` que ainda não existe.

Se pensar na instrução em português percebe melhor o problema: "Crie uma variável `j` e coloque nela o valor da variável `j` + 1." Mas se acabou de criar, então não pode colocar o valor baseado numa variável que não existe.

Faça antes assim:

```
int j = 0; //declara fora do for

for (int i = 1; i  <= qtdLinha;  i++) {
    if (pessoaJuridicaPublicaService.getPorId(Long.parseLong(dadosUsuario[1])) == null) {
        j = j + 1; //apenas incrementa aqui
    }
}
```

Pode não só fazer uso do `++` para simplificar, assim como dar um nome melhor à variável:

```
int camposVazios = 0;

for (int i = 1; i  <= qtdLinha;  i++) {
    if (pessoaJuridicaPublicaService.getPorId(Long.parseLong(dadosUsuario[1])) == null) {
        camposVazios++;
    }
}
```